# How to setup node js server for application for local network?

Tags: node.js, networking, localhost, lan

I have a local network where I have multiple pc. I want to install on node js application 1 device on my local network and want to access all other devices. I also try to access the application with all using ip address and port number. It show my application. But problem is when I tried to post any data like want to sign in and I input phone and password I does't send the data to my webserver.

How can I access my node js application from another pc of my local area network ?

Comment: "does[n]'t send the data to my webserver" where does it send it?  I assume it works locally?  Are there any `localhost` or equivalent IP address in the html form action?  have you checked browser development tools to see what's happening?